# "grep -B 1" one line per result

Tags: grep, formatting

Hi all hopefully the below makes sense.

I have a file it contains a lot of junk as well as some data I wish to keep, the data I wish to extract is any line containing "=>" plus the previous line, my issue is however I really need to output (the line containing => and the previous line) to be contained on the same line
Example:

```
junk
input <= lala
thing1 => lululu
more junk
more junks
even more junks
input <= junk
extra junk
hello123 => lelele
input <= lololo
thing3 => kt
```

What I have currently using is using "grep -B 1 '=>' file1" is:

```
input <= lala
thing1 => lululu
--
extra junk
hello123 => lelele
--
input <= lololo
thing3 => kt
```

What I really want would be or something similar.

```
input <= lala thing1 => lululu
--
extra junk hello123 => lelele
--
input <= lololo thing3 => kt
```

Comment: Is the post by alfasin correct for you.  It does not give what you have requested in you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash, you can do it in a one-liner:

```
t="";for i in $(grep -B 1 '=>' tmp.txt) ; do if [[ "$i" != "--" ]] ;then t="$t $i"; else echo "$t";echo "--";t="";fi;done;echo "$t"
```

OUTPUT:

```
alfasi$ t="";for i in $(grep -B 1 '=>' tmp.txt) ; do if [[ "$i" != "--" ]] ;then t="$t $i"; else echo "$t";echo "--";t="";fi;done;echo "$t"
 input <= lala thing1 => lululu
--
 extra junk hello123 => lelele
--
 input <= lololo thing3 => kt
lgml-alfasi2:bin alfasi$
```

Comment: Not sure why, but with this, the two last output line is joined together. Can you post output you get?

Comment: @Jotne I added the output from my shell to the answer

Comment: But this is not what OP want??  Its quit different from his request.

Answer (score 0):

The process of reading the input is not too difficult using a `here string` and then a `toggle` within a `while` loop. There are a number of different ways to do this. This just came to mind first.

```
#!/bin/bash

# read input filename as first argument
ifn="$1"  

# validate file is readable
[ -r "$ifn" ] || {
    printf "error: file not readable '%s'.\n" "$ifn"
    exit 1
}

declare -i a=0    # use 'a' as first/second line toggle

## for each line in results
while read -r line; do

    [ ${line:0:1} == '-' ] && { a=0; continue; }  # skip -- lines

    [ $a -eq 0 ] && sav="$line"   # if a=0, save line

    if [ $a -eq 1 ]; then         # if a=1, form output
        myline="${sav} ${line}"
        # printf -- "--\n"        # uncomment for separator
        printf "%s\n" "$myline"
    fi

    [ $a -eq 0 ] && a=1 || a=0    # toggle a=0/1

done <<< "$(grep -B 1 '=>' "$ifn")"

exit 0
```

**input**

```
$ cat dat/twotoone.dat
junk
input <= lala
thing1 => lululu
more junk
more junks
even more junks
input <= junk
extra junk
hello123 => lelele
input <= lololo
thing3 => kt
```

**output**

```
$ bash twointoone.sh dat/twotoone.dat
input <= lala thing1 => lululu
extra junk hello123 => lelele
input <= lololo thing3 => kt
```

**note:** if you want the separators between the lines, then add the following before you print `$myline`:

```
        printf -- "--\n"
```

**output with separator**

```
$ bash twointoone.sh dat/twotoone.dat
--
input <= lala thing1 => lululu
--
extra junk hello123 => lelele
--
input <= lololo thing3 => kt
```

Comment: works perfectly as well gave the answer to alfasin as his was the first I saw, but this works just as well.

Comment: Glad I could help. With Bash, there are always multiple ways to skin every cat...

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to do with `awk`

```
awk '/=>/ {print a,$0"\n--"} {a=$0}' file
input <= lala thing1 => lululu
--
extra junk hello123 => lelele
--
input <= lololo thing3 => kt
--
```

If you do not like the last `--` to be printed:

```
awk '/=>/ {print (f++?"--\n":"")a,$0} {a=$0}' file
input <= lala thing1 => lululu
--
extra junk hello123 => lelele
--
input <= lololo thing3 => kt
```